# Any coolosxapps.net alternative? (New OS X Software Blog)

Tags: macos, website, blogging, resources

I remember I used to almost religiously hit the **coolosxapps.net** website to find newly available freewares (mostly) for OS X.  Now that the site was sold and is not available, I'm having trouble finding a similar website or blog.

### Anybody know of any other good websites and/or blogs out there?

- coolosxapps.com is usually pretty static now, I need to find a good one that is updated often.
- Apple.com/downloads is all over the place and doesn't even have some of the really awesome apps available like Cord, Fluid, Gmail Notifr, Simplify, etc..

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MacAppstorm](http://mac.appstorm.net/) seems to be pretty nice. Their reviews (so far) have been pretty comprehensive as well.

Following a load of mac indie developers on twitter works wonders for getting info about new apps coming out (tell me if you want a list of indie devs on twitter for this purpose).

[Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net) also covers new apps, but has a lot of other stuff thrown in as well (which is a good or a bad thing depending on what you like).

Comment: +1 for Twitter (surprisingly effective for this) and Gruber's Fireball. Have bookmarked MacAppstorm for the weekend. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is an update tracker not a blog, but does link to similar apps and so is great for discovery of new tools; a different way to approach the same problem (how to find new software):

http://osx.iusethis.com/

I also sometimes keep an eye on [MacUpdate](http://www.macupdate.com/), it has one-line summaries to quickly scan what new software may do.

Answer (score 1):

I would just check general Apple blogs as they should list any new/upcoming software.

I personally like [The unofficial Apple Weblog](http://www.tuaw.com/)

Another one I just found from Google was [The Apple Blog](http://theappleblog.com/)